# What regular expression should I use to validate this input?

Tags: c#, regex

I need to write a regular expression to verify if a file input follows a rule:

`A111B2_3_C.exe`

in which:

- A: compulsory, it must be a'A'
- 111: compulsory, it is a natural number
- B: compulsory, it must be a'B'
- 2: compulsory, it is in range from 1->6
- _: compulsory, it must be '_'
- 3: compulsory, it must be a nature number
- _: optional if C followed, it must be '_'
- C: optional, C is a natural number
- .exe: is the end extension of the file

It should be accepted this one: A111B2_3_.exe as well. but A111B2_3_0.exe is not accepted. the number after 3_ must be greater than 0.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Um, why do you write `C` if it's supposed to be a number?

Comment: nature number ? O.o . You mean Natural number ?

Comment: Provide examples of what is valid and what is not besides the first one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bit hard to understand your requirements, but here's a regex that should do what you want:

```
A\d+B[1-6]_\d+(_\d+)?\.exe
```

Explanation:

1. `A` -- The letter 'A'
2. `\d+` -- 1 or more numbers
3. `B` -- The letter 'B'
4. `[1-6]` -- A single number: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, or 6
5. `_` -- An underscore
6. `\d+` -- 1 or more numbers
7. `(_\d+)?` -- Optionally, an underscore followed by 1 or more numbers
8. `\.` -- A period
9. `exe` -- The letters 'exe'

**Edit:** In response to your comments, here is a regex that will also accept `A111B2_3_.exe`:

```
A\d+B[1-6]_\d+(_\d*)?\.exe
```

I changed the last `\d+` (one or more numbers) to `\d*` (zero or more numbers).

**Edit 2**: Now I've changed `\d*` to `([1-9]\d*)?`. What that means is left as an exercise to the reader.

```
A\d+B[1-6]_\d+(_([1-9]\d*)?)?\.exe
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot. But I would be also accept: A111B2_3_.exe as well. How can modify the current one for this?

Comment: thanks. It is getting better. I forgot to mention, A111B2_3_0.exe is not accepted, the number after 3_ must be great than 0. thanks!

Comment: I've edited my edit. At this point you should understand the regex well enough to edit it yourself if you need something else changed.

Comment: thanks. it works great. Yes, I have learnt some more knowledge from it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"^A(\d+)B([1-6])_(\d+)(_(\d+))?\.exe$");
var match = regex.Match(filename);
if (match.Success) {
    var firstNumber = match.Groups[1].Value; // the '111' part (number)
    var secondNumber = match.Groups[2].Value; // the '2' part (1-6)
    var thirdNumber = match.Groups[3].Value; // the '3' part (number)
    var hasFourthNumber = match.Groups[4].Success;
    string fourthNumber = null;
    if (hasFourthNumber) {
        fourthNumber = match.Groups[5].Value; // the 'C' part (number)
    }

    // TODO: Do stuff with the extracted numbers
    // TODO: Give better variable names...
}
```

Check out a working version here: http://regexr.com?2vjto

Comment: @atomblad: while you may have presented working code, I think your answer would be better if you explained what the regular expression means rather than just giving the expression and showing what it returns. Otherwise, sequences like `(\d+)` will remain steeped in mystery.

Comment: great. your provided sample works for me after changing something. but at least it is really the solution and also the link provided is very productive! thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi, I tried your solution but I got this problem for: A111B2_3_.exe how should I modify it to accept this one? if there is a number between 3 and ".exe" then there must be " _ " in between: so: A111B2_3_.exe and A111B2_3_123.exe are both accepted but A111B2_3__123.exe is not accepted. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Oh, that wasn't in your original specification of the problem. Should there *always* be that extra underscore character or is it optional? You originally wrote that the underscore was only required when followed by a number.

Comment: For now you can change it to: ^A(\d+)B([1-6])_(\d+)(_)?(\d+)?\.exe$ and change the "hasFourthNumber" check to match.Groups[5].Success  - sorry for bad formatting. Writing this on my phone.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this shuld work:

```
A\d\d\dB[1-6]_\d(_\d)?\.exe
```

This assumes that 111 is 3 digit, 2 is one digit and C in one digit.
If 111,2 and C can have more digits:

```
A(\d+)B[1-6]_(\d+)(_(\d+))?\.exe
```